# Defining a new field conditionally using put function with user-defined formats

Tags: sas

I am trying to define a new value for an observation with a user defined format. However, my if/then/else statement seems to only work for observations with a year value of "2014". The put statements are not working for other values. In SAS, the put statement is blue in the first statement, and black in the other two. Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Does anyone know what I am missing here? Here is my complete code:

```
data claims_t03_group;
    set output.claims_t02_group;
    if year = "2014" then test = put(compress(lookup,"_"),$G_14_PROD35.);
    else if year = "2015" then test = put(compress(lookup,"_"),$G_15_PROD35.);
    else test = put(compress(lookup,"_"),$G_16_PROD35.);
    run;
```

Here is an example of what I mean when I say that the process seems to "work" for 2014:

[image]

As you can see, when the Year value is 2014, the format lookup works correctly, and the test field returns the value I am expecting. However, for years 2015 and 2016, the test field returns the lookup value without any formatting.

Comment: `put` should not be in blue if it's in that code above - it's not in mine, anyway.  Can you verify that it's still in blue for you?  If so, then you haven't transcribed your code properly, or you have some other problem earlier in your code (try taking just this data step and putting in a new window).

Comment: Just to clarify, it's blue if it is a `statement` and black if it's a `function`.  `put` is both things, so it's up to the syntax parser to figure that out; if you have it as blue, then it thinks you're using the `statement`, meaning it doesn't see the `test=` part probably.

Comment: Finally, you need to explain what 'working' means.  You get values in the year=2014 but nothing in the other two?  Or you get values from 2014 format in all three years?  Would be very helpful to put some example in here with made up data - make up a couple of formats (you can use VALUE statements) and some example rows, and edit it into the question.

Comment: Your feedback is really useful. Let me know if I can make this more clear.

Comment: Do all three formats have the same START values, like your example above?  Or is it more like 0001/0002/0003 for first, 0004/0005/0006 for second, 0007/0008/0009 for third?  What I'm getting at is, there are 2 possibilities right now: either it's getting to the rigth IF/ELSE but that format is broken/doesn't exist, or it's on the wrong IF/ELSE and the value doesn't have a map on that format.  If all formats have the same subset of START values, then the second isn't possible.

Comment: Show some actual data values in the form of a DATA step that we can run. Show your format definitions in the form of PROC FORMAT code we can run.

Answer (score 0):

Your code utilises user-defined formats, `$G_14_PROD.`-`$G_16_PROD.`. My guess would be that there is a problem with one or more of these, but unless you can provide the format definitions it will be difficult to assist you further.

Try running the following and sharing the resulting output dataset `work.prdfmts`:

```
proc sql noprint;
  select cats(libname,'.',memname) into :myfmtlib 
  from sashelp.vcatalg 
  where objname = 'G_14_PROD';
quit;

proc format cntlout = prdfmts library=&myfmtlib;
  select G_14_PROD G_15_PROD G_16_PROD;
run;
```

N.B. this assumes that you only have one catalogue containing a format with that name, and that the format definitions for all 3 formats are contained in the same catalogue. If not, you will need to adapt this a bit and run it once for each format to find and export the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Not that it solves your actual problem, but you could eliminate the `IF/THEN` by using the `PUTC()` function instead.

```
data have ;
  do year=2014,2015,2016;
    do lookup='00_01','00_02' ;
       output;
    end;
  end;
run;

proc format ;
 value $G_14_PROD '0001'='2014 - 1' '0002'='2014 - 2' ;
 value $G_15_PROD '0001'='2015 - 1' '0002'='2015 - 2' ;
 value $G_16_PROD '0001'='2016 - 1' '0002'='2016 - 2' ;
run;

data want ;
  set have ;
  length test $35 ;
  if 2014 <= year <= 2016 then
    test = putc(compress(lookup,'_'),cats('$G_',year-2000,'_PROD.'))
  ;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    year    lookup      test
 1     2014    00_01     2014 - 1
 2     2014    00_02     2014 - 2
 3     2015    00_01     2015 - 1
 4     2015    00_02     2015 - 2
 5     2016    00_01     2016 - 1
 6     2016    00_02     2016 - 2
```